# Delete selected items from JList in Java

Tags: java, jlist

How can I remove something I've selected in a Left list, to the Right list?

I watched a tutorial in YouTube, where the guy did this code, but it's not looking nice. I mean, when I add something of the Left list to the Right list, I need to remove what was selected of the left list.

```
button = new JButton("Move -->");
button.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            rightlist.setListData(leftlist.getSelectedValues());

        }
    }
);
```

So, this button puts what I selected in the left list, to the right list. But as I said, I want to remove the items that are selected from the left list. So it will only appear at the right list, and not in the left list.

How can I do that?

Comment: `setListData` sets all of the data in the list.  So one approach would be to keep a left List and a right List, and use those to update the JList.

Comment: Duplicate. Answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402658/delete-selected-item-from-jlist

Comment: Thank you all, sorry for the repost, im new, sorry. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have isn't bad, and it actually does what you want:

```
button.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) ->
{
    rightlist.setListData(leftlist.getSelectedValues());
```

Now, you need to remove those Elements from the underlying `ListModel`. Assuming you have a `DefaultListModel`, you could do it like this:

```
    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) leftlist.getModel();
    for (Object elem : leftlist.getSelectedValues)
        model.removeElement(elem);
}
```

For more information, see the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) for `DefaultListModel`.