# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with ActionListener in JList

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, indexoutofboundsexception, jlist

I looked at the other questions that look related to mine but they didn't  "solve" my problem. I received the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and the code I'm working on is deleting the "contact" in the JList named contactList.

I have implemented a button that will simply delete a "contact" in the contactList. What the program is supposed to do is if the button deletes "Broadcast", which is the first element in contactList, will return an error by outputting a display message. Otherwise, it is supposed to simply remove the contact from the contact list.

The problem I have right now is that it produces the arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when removing a contact. Not only that, it also prints out the error line from the other if statement. Removing broadcast outputs the error message but still shows the arraryIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Also, I'm not exactly sure if I did the first if statement correctly.
I've included the necessary code at the beginning along with the error I got after the code was tested.

```
private JList<String> listContacts;
listContacts = new JList<String>(controller.getContacts());
// gets contact list from controller class which gets contact list from client class.
private JButton btDeleteUser;

JButton deleteUser = new JButton("Delete User");

deleteUser.addActionListener(new MyButtonListener5());

class MyButtonListener5 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        DefaultListModel<String> list = (DefaultListModel)(listContacts.getModel());
        String contact = listContacts.getSelectedValue();
        int j = -1;
        for(int i = list.getSize()-1; i >= 0; i--){
            if(list.getElementAt(i).equals("Broadcast")){
                controller.displayMsg("[ERROR] You cannot delete broadcast\n");
            }
            else if(list.getElementAt(i).equals(contact) && i != j){
                j = i;
            }
        }
        if(j != -1){
            (DefaultListModel)list.remove(j);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
[java] Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JList$4 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel
 [java]     at edu.ucsb.cs56.projects.networking.chat.chatclient.view.ClientWindow$MyButtonListener5.actionPerformed(ClientWindow.java:391)
 [java]     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 [java]     at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 [java]     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 [java]     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 [java]     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
 [java]     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
 [java]     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
 [java]     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
 [java]     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
 [java]     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
 [java]     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
 [java]     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
 [java]     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
 [java]     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
 [java]     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
 [java]     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
 [java]     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
 [java]     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 [java]     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: You change your list while iterating over it.
Remember the item you want to delete and remove it outside the iteration.

Comment: Are you saying that I should have it create a new JList and put the new contacts in it?

Comment: No but when you remove the item and then continue iterating, the indexes of the items in the list are not the same as before. You can avoid that for example by just calculating the element to be removed during iteration and remove it afterwards.

Comment: So you're saying that I should remove the item after finding the index it's in?

Comment: Exactly, calculate the index in the loop and remove the element outside the loop

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I think you are now removing the first element in the list when broadcast is selected. Note that you only need to either iterate backwards or delete outside the loop.

Comment: @garnulf I tested it and selecting broadcast will print out the message but also the exception. I also tried deleting the other contacts and the same result happens. I do want to try deleting outside of the loop, advise how I should go in that direction?

Comment: You can initialize your int with -1 and delete only when it is not still -1

Comment: @garnulf I tried testing your way but I think I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. Are you saying that the int i starts at the bottom of the list and keeps iterating up before -1?

Comment: The int j should be initialized with -1.
The deletion should only be performed if j is not -1.

Comment: @garnulf I updated the code, did I implement it correctly or did I miss read your directions?

Comment: The remove should be only done if `j != -1`

Comment: @garnulf Look at updated code, I feel like I'm getting somewhere but I don't see it.

Comment: Now see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402658/delete-selected-item-from-jlist
It seems you have to write `(DefaultListModel)list.remove(j)` 
Strange.

Comment: @garnulf I looked at that link you gave me and I tried that and it said (DefaultListModel) isn't a statement. Then I looked at my code and changed it all to match or at least look like that in the link. I compiled it and I was presented with a new error, ClassCastException where JList can't be cast to DefaultListModel. Should I move this issue to a new post?

Comment: No you need braces. `(DefaultListModel)(listContacts.getModel())`

Comment: @garnulf did as you said and same error.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Can you update the code, too?
It seems from the error that you still call remove at the JList.

Comment: I updated the code and from there, I got this error. 
`[javac] Compiling 1 source file to /fs/student/whuang/cs56/cs56-networking-chat/build
[javac] /fs/student/ClientWindow.java:403: error: not a statement
[javac]   (DefaultListModel)list.remove(j);
[javac]   ^
[javac] 1 error`

Comment: The method is removeElementAt for DefaultListModel.
Also it seems that you have to initialize your JList with a DefaultListModel:
JList<String> listContacts = new JList<>(new DefaultListModel<String>());

Comment: I updated the code and I forgot to include it. Is it still possible to modify it from there?

Answer (score 3):

Basics:

If you have 5 elements in a JList, then the last element's index will be 4, and the size of the list will be 5.

Problem:

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= list.getSize(); i++){
```

Here you say to loop trough from 0 to the list's size inclusively, thus when `i` reaches the length of the list, then you will try to get the element with the same index, wich doesn't exist.

You need to change <= to <

Comment: I modified that and I'm still getting the error related to just removing the contact.

Comment: @whuang The way to solve that problem is to iterate over the array backwards. Use the `for (int i = list.getSize() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {` as the for loop

Comment: I did modify it again and I'm still getting the same error.